# c++ sndPlaySound skip to 10 seconds

Tags: c++, audio, ifstream, playsound

I'm searching now for hours and I hope you can help me.

I am programming an musicplayer which reads an *.wav File via ifstream to an buffer and then i play the sound via sndPlaysound(). That works but now I want to pause the played song and then continue later and I want to know if anybody has any suggestions how I can skip to e.g. 10 seconds in the wav file so that I'm not starting at the beginning again.

Here is the code of the things I did until now:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib")
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

Wave::Wave(char * filename)
{
    buffer = 0;

    std::ifstream infile(filename, std::ios::binary);

    /*here is some irrelevant code I omitted*/

    infile.seekg(0, std::ios::end);  //move to end
    int length = infile.tellg();   //
    buffer = new char[length];    //allocate memory
    infile.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);   //move to start
    infile.read(buffer, length); //save in buffer

    totalTime = (length - 44) / bytesPerSec; //total time of *.wav

    infile.close();
}

void Wave::play(bool async)
{
    if (async)
        sndPlaySound((LPCTSTR)buffer,  SND_MEMORY | SND_ASYNC);
    else
        sndPlaySound((LPCTSTR)buffer,  SND_MEMORY);
}
```

and I am searching for any ideas how to make a method like this

```
Wave::play(bool async, int x)
{
     /*start playing *.wav at x seconds*/
}
```

Thanks for every answer or idea

Comment: `sndPlaySound()` always plays from the beginning, you can't seek it.  You will have to use the `waveOut...` functions instead.  You can use the `mmio...` functions to read the wave file so you can handle its WAV chunks correctly.  See the [Waveform Audio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757715.aspx) and [Multimedia Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743586.aspx) sections of MSDN for more details.

Comment: Instead of "searching", _read_ and _study_ the documentation. It takes more than "hours".